# groovy updating config file

Tags: parsing, properties, groovy

I have a groovy configuration file that looks something like

```
section1 {
    prop1 = val1
    prop2 = val2
    section2 {
       prop3 = val3
    {
}

// other style properties in this file
anotherprop = someval

// as well as some other statements
println "hello there"
```

And I'd like to write a groovy script to change the value of prop3 for example. Is there a good way to do this in groovy? It's a little tougher since the file contains multiple styles of properties as well as the println.

Comment: btw: what is the use case for replacing the property?

Comment: I'm working with some 3rd party code that exposes some configuration files that I can change and I want to change them programmatically. While the printlns are not crucial to the properties, I want to leave the file as in tact as possible.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to modify the configuration after it has been read by the application? So that your app-config will overwrite the 3rd party app config?

Comment: Not sure, I'll have to check, but I believe all of these config files are read during startup.

Comment: afaik, all config files are already read when bootstrap code is executed - you could user the configSlurper to read another config and overwrite the 3rd party one...

Comment: @Ralf, that's where the whole issue with the printlns come in (and other stuff that's in the config file). If I use the ConfigSlurper those statements get removed

Comment: my suggestion this time wasn't to use the slurper in order to modify the original file but to read a file which overwrites the third parry config only in memory...

Answer (score 0):

As I do understand, you want to modify a configuration **file**.

Since you have `println` and other statements in the file, reading the file with the configurationSlurper isn't an option.

I guess the easies way (but I expect to get downvotes for thsi solution )-: is to use a regsub:

```
def config = new File('config.groovy').getText()
def newValue = 18
def newConfig = config.replaceAll(/(?ms)(prop3[ \t]*=[ \t]*)([0-9]*)/,'$1'+newValue)
new File('config.groovy').write(newConfig)
```

this should be pretty stable for most cases...

Comment: I thought about doing something like that but it doesn't handle nested properties too well. For example, If I had a prop3 inside one block and prop3 inside another block.

Comment: Do you have the chance to "mark" your property? maybe with sourrounding comments? Or an inline comment? `myProperty = 15; //<- will be replaced`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, please see my comments to your question above.